# mongodb find multiple referenced documents

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a database in mongodb which has two collections: *cards* and *teams*.
My *cards* collection structure is:

```
{"Card":{"_id":{"$oid":"5a46626e150ed3f847f01bac"},"Number":1,"Page":1,"Team":[{"$oid":"5a465ca9150ed3f847f01b92"}]}}
{"Card":{"_id":{"$oid":"5a466d96150ed3f847f01bad"},"Number":18,"Page":6,"Team":[{"$oid":"5a465ca9150ed3f847f01b92"}]}}
{"Card":{"_id":{"$oid":"5a466de6150ed3f847f01bae"},"Number":35,"Page":8, "Team":[{"$oid":"5a465ca9150ed3f847f01b92"}]}}
```

and my *teams* collection structure is:

```
{"Team":{"_id":{"$oid":"5a465ca9150ed3f847f01b92"},"Name":"NA","Coach":"NA"}}
```

I want to print all cards information, that is, for each card, I want to print it's id, number, page and the informations of the team(id, name and coach).
I tryied:

```
var team = db.cards.find()
while(team.hasNext()){team_data = db.teams.find({"Team._id":{$in:team.Cards.Team}}).toArray()}
```

but it gives me:

```
2018-01-02T18:35:57.588+0000 E QUERY    [thread1] TypeError: team.Cards is undefined :
@(shell):1:62
```

then I tryied:

```
var team = db.cards.find()
while(team.hasNext()){team_data = db.teams.find({"Team._id":{$in:team.Team}}).toArray()}
```

and it gave me:

```
2018-01-02T18:36:21.620+0000 E QUERY    [thread1] Error: error: {
        "ok" : 0,
        "errmsg" : "$in needs an array",
        "code" : 2,
        "codeName" : "BadValue"
} :
_getErrorWithCode@src/mongo/shell/utils.js:25:13
DBCommandCursor@src/mongo/shell/query.js:717:1
DBQuery.prototype._exec@src/mongo/shell/query.js:117:28
DBQuery.prototype.hasNext@src/mongo/shell/query.js:288:5
DBQuery.prototype.toArray@src/mongo/shell/query.js:337:12
@(shell):1:35
```

finally I tryied:

```
var team = db.cards.find()
team.forEach(team_data = db.teams.find({"Team._id":{$in:team.Team}}).toArray())
```

but it also doesn't work:

```
2018-01-02T18:28:28.345+0000 E QUERY    [thread1] Error: error: {
        "ok" : 0,
        "errmsg" : "$in needs an array",
        "code" : 2,
        "codeName" : "BadValue"
} :
_getErrorWithCode@src/mongo/shell/utils.js:25:13
DBCommandCursor@src/mongo/shell/query.js:717:1
```

How can I properly print all informations for each card?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it one of the following ways.

Iterating cursor

```
var teamCursor = db.cards.find();

while (teamCursor.hasNext()) {
   var team = teamCursor.next();
   var team_data = db.teams.find({"Team._id":{$in:team.Card.Team}}).toArray();
   // format output here 
}
```

Cursor's foreach

```
db.cards.find().forEach( function(team) {        
  var team_data = db.teams.find({"Team._id":{$in:team.Card.Team}}).toArray();
  // format output here 
});
```

Using aggregation in 3.6 ( Preferred )

```
db.cards.aggregate([
{"$lookup":{
    "from":"teams",
    "localField":"Card.Team",
    "foreignField":"Team._id",
    "as":"team_data"}
},
{"$replaceRoot":{
    "newRoot":{
      "$mergeObjects":[
        {"$arrayElemAt":["$team_data",0]},
        "$$ROOT"
    ]}
  }
},
{"$project":{"team_data":0}}
])
```